# Multiple Markdown translations per cell on jupyter notebooks

Tags: html, tabs, jupyter-notebook, jquery-ui-tabs, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

Is there a native way or widget on jupyter notebooks to set a markdown cell to create something like `html tabs` so I can add documentation on each language I want instead of creating 3 different notebooks that will add complexity in the maintainability of my experiments?

Being able to add something like this will suffice

```
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Spanish')">Spanish</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'English')">English</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Japanese')">Japanese</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="Spanish" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Spanish Explanation</h3>
  <p>This is an explanation in Spanish</p>
</div>

<div id="English" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>English Explanation</h3>
  <p>This is an explanation in English</p>
</div>

<div id="Japanese" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Japanese Explanation</h3>
  <p>This is an explanation in Japanese</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ipywidgets includes [tabs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Tabs) and to make it look like a markdown cell you could either hide the code or make a Voila app. There are several extensions to do that, such as `Hide input`,`Hide input all`, & [hide_code](https://github.com/kirbs-/hide_code). (The first two are part of the [community-contributed unofficial extensions (jupyter_contrib_nbextensions)](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that get installed as bundle. Voila is described [here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) and there is a [gallery of examples](https://voila-gallery.org/).

For something simpler that works natively in a notebook markdown cell and renders well for when the notebooks may be statically represented, there is [collapsible markdown](https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/16041f2426450e73f5df9391f7f7ae5f). A fancier version of this called [Collapsible Headings](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/collapsible_headings/readme.html#collapsible-headings) is included as part of the unofficial extensions bundle I mentioned above.

Comment: If you want a quickly accessible environment to test out that demo code at the link for the tabs widget, go to [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyter-extension) and click the `launch binder` badge. After the sessions spins up run the code in the notebook that opens. Then paste the demo code from that link in a new cell. Add `import ipywidgets as widgets` as the first line of that cell you just made, and it will show the tabs.